# Add input field to every item in cart

Tags: woocommerce, field, cart

I am trying to add a new field on my cart.php file.

I actually want to insert a URL field, so user can set a URL for each order item.

I tried to use a code from another post here but I can't get it to work.

The first and the second functions are working but when it comes to the third one, `'woocommerce_get_item_data'` the `$cart_item['url']` doesn't contain anything even if I add something in the field and I press Update Cart.

`$cart_totals[ $cart_item_key ]['url']` from the first function is outputting the right value when the page load.

I don't know what to do now, thanks for any help. 
Here is the code

Add the field
cart/cart.php

```
<td class="product-url">
    <?php
        $html = sprintf( '<div class="url"><input type="text" name="cart[%s][url]" value="%s" size="4" title="Url" class="input-text url text" /></div>', $cart_item_key, esc_attr( $values['url'] ) );
        echo $html;
    ?>
</td>
```

functions.php

```
// get from session your URL variable and add it to item
add_filter('woocommerce_get_cart_item_from_session', 'cart_item_from_session', 99, 3);
function cart_item_from_session( $data, $values, $key ) {
    $data['url'] = isset( $values['url'] ) ? $values['url'] : '';
    return $data;
}

// this one does the same as woocommerce_update_cart_action() in plugins\woocommerce\woocommerce-functions.php
// but with your URL variable
// this might not be the best way but it works
add_action( 'init', 'update_cart_action', 9);
function update_cart_action() {
    global $woocommerce;
    if ( ( ! empty( $_POST['update_cart'] ) || ! empty( $_POST['proceed'] ) ) ) {
        $cart_totals = isset( $_POST['cart'] ) ? $_POST['cart'] : '';
        if ( sizeof( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
            foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
                if ( isset( $cart_totals[ $cart_item_key ]['url'] ) ) {
                    $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents[ $cart_item_key ]['url'] = $cart_totals[ $cart_item_key ]['url'];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// this is in Order summary. It show Url variable under product name. Same place where Variations are shown.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'item_data', 10, 2 );
function item_data( $data, $cart_item ) {
    if ( isset( $cart_item['url'] ) ) {
        $data['url'] = array('name' => 'Url', 'value' => $cart_item['url']);
    }
    return $data;
}

// this adds Url as meta in Order for item
add_action ('woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', 'add_item_meta', 10, 2);
function add_item_meta( $item_id, $values ) {
    woocommerce_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'Url', $values['url'] );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add a textarea field to a WooCommerce cart item**

First, we just need to add the textarea field. We use the woocommerce_after_cart_item_name hook so our textarea will appear after the product name.

```
<?php
/**
 * Add a text field to each cart item
 */
function prefix_after_cart_item_name( $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
 $notes = isset( $cart_item['notes'] ) ? $cart_item['notes'] : '';
 printf(
 '<div><textarea class="%s" id="cart_notes_%s" data-cart-id="%s">%s</textarea></div>',
 'prefix-cart-notes',
 $cart_item_key,
 $cart_item_key,
 $notes
 );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_item_name', 'prefix_after_cart_item_name', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Enqueue our JS file
 */
function prefix_enqueue_scripts() {
 wp_register_script( 'prefix-script', trailingslashit( plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) ) . 'update-cart-item-ajax.js', array( 'jquery-blockui' ), time(), true );
 wp_localize_script(
 'prefix-script',
 'prefix_vars',
 array(
 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
 )
 );
 wp_enqueue_script( 'prefix-script' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'prefix_enqueue_scripts' );
´´´
At the moment, the user will be able to enter text into the field but the text won’t save. We are going to use some AJAX to save the text.

The code above not only adds the textarea to the cart item, it also enqueues a JavaScript file ready for our AJAX.

It’s assumed that you’re using the code on this page to create a new plugin. If so, you should create a new JS file with the code below and place the file in the root directory of your plugin.

However, if you’ve added the PHP above to your theme functions.php or as a snippet on your site, you’ll need to change the location of the JS file by updating line 21 of the snippet above to identify the location of the JS file.

´´´
(function($){
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('.prefix-cart-notes').on('change keyup paste',function(){
 $('.cart_totals').block({
 message: null,
 overlayCSS: {
 background: '#fff',
 opacity: 0.6
 }
 });
 var cart_id = $(this).data('cart-id');
 $.ajax(
 {
 type: 'POST',
 url: prefix_vars.ajaxurl,
 data: {
 action: 'prefix_update_cart_notes',
 security: $('#woocommerce-cart-nonce').val(),
 notes: $('#cart_notes_' + cart_id).val(),
 cart_id: cart_id
 },
 success: function( response ) {
 $('.cart_totals').unblock();
 }
 }
 )
 });
 });
})(jQuery);

´´´

Now, when the user types anything, the contents of the text field get sent back to the server ready to be saved as meta data to the cart item.

´´´
<?php
/**
 * Update cart item notes
 */
function prefix_update_cart_notes() {
 // Do a nonce check
 if( ! isset( $_POST['security'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['security'], 'woocommerce-cart' ) ) {
 wp_send_json( array( 'nonce_fail' => 1 ) );
 exit;
 }
 // Save the notes to the cart meta
 $cart = WC()->cart->cart_contents;
 $cart_id = $_POST['cart_id'];
 $notes = $_POST['notes'];
 $cart_item = $cart[$cart_id];
 $cart_item['notes'] = $notes;
 WC()->cart->cart_contents[$cart_id] = $cart_item;
 WC()->cart->set_session();
 wp_send_json( array( 'success' => 1 ) );
 exit;
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_prefix_update_cart_notes', 'prefix_update_cart_notes' );

function prefix_checkout_create_order_line_item( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
 foreach( $item as $cart_item_key=>$cart_item ) {
 if( isset( $cart_item['notes'] ) ) {
 $item->add_meta_data( 'notes', $cart_item['notes'], true );
 }
 }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'prefix_checkout_create_order_line_item', 10, 4 );

´´´

The prefix_update_cart_notes function does a security check using the WooCommerce cart nonce then saves the content of the textarea as meta data in the cart item. You can check out this article for more information about updating cart meta for items that have already been added to the cart.

Add the custom text to the order meta
Finally, we want to pass our meta data to the order so that we can use it after the customer has checked out. The prefix_checkout_create_order_line_item function takes care of that, iterating through each item and saving notes when it finds them.


https://pluginrepublic.com/how-to-add-an-input-field-to-woocommerce-cart-items/
```